# Musicplayer that shows BPM information and allows sorting according to BPM

Tags: music-player

Is there an music player that shows the value in the BPM tag? I would also like it to sort according to BPM.

Comment: I just checked winamp for droid and it doesn't sort by bpm. ARGH...the search continues

Comment: Unfortunately I find almost all of Androids media player apps lacking support for any sort of advanced sorting.

Answer (score 1):

As far as just showing BPM, PowerAMP does that quite nicely while the song is actually playing and in the info section. Sorting is a different story (though lots of other great sort options). and of course this is a paid app. Now that you've mentioned it though, I might email the dev about it.

Neutron MP is also an interesting program that shows everything from BPM to sampling rate to crossfade sliders to a bunch of other advanced dj controls that you'll probably never touch. It's slow as molasses though and while it's uber advanced, it's not particularly user-friendly. Also I could find no sortation options at all.

I tried (unsuccessfully) to find BPM info in the following music apps: 3, WinAmp, BoomBoxoid, Meridian, Zimly, and MixZing. I also tried the tagging programs iTag & Pimp My Music with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Droid DJ. It says its got a beat countneed I don't think it'll sort by bpm but it may be worth a try if you don't find exactly what you need.

Comment: My files are already tagged with BPM data. I need software to simply read the data from the tag. I don't see that Droid DJ does that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say with perfect certainty, but I've not seen anything like this in any of the major music player apps, which all struggle each in their own way to provide any extra-functionality. However, winamp for android was just released and is supposed to be fairly feature rich. Check there, maybe.